# will apt-get autoremove break other dependencies?

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

I want to use `apt-get autoremove` to remove `liba` for instance, but I'm not sure whether it is smart enough to preserve other dependencies. For instance, if `liba` depends on `libb`, while `libc` also depends on `libb`, will

```
sudo apt-get autoremove liba
```

remove `libb` or not? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

None of the `apt-get` or other APT tools will ever break dependencies (except for bugs).

You don't run `apt-get autoremove liba`, just `apt-get autoremove`. The whole point of `autoremove` is that it discovers what there is to remove.

When you run `apt-get autoremove`, check the list of packages to make sure you aren't relying on any of the packages that it will remove. A package that you use all the time could have been pulled in as a dependency of another package without you having noticed that.

Comment: I made a stupid conceptual mistake due to laziness. Thanks.

Comment: You *can* run `apt-get autoremove liba` to remove `liba` and any other packages which are no longer used and are set to be removed automatically when the `autoremove` command is run.

Answer (score 1):

The `autoremove` option to `apt-get` will only remove the packages which depend on `liba` and packages which are no longer used.

Answer (score 0):

From the apt-get man page:

> autoremove is used to remove packages that were automatically
>   installed to satisfy dependencies for some package and that are no
>   more needed.

autoremove doesn't accept any package as argument (the command is just `apt-get autoremove`). No dependency will be broken.

Comment: Not entirely true. It does accept arguments. `apt-get autoremove foo` will remove the packages which are no longer used, as well as `foo` and its dependants.

Comment: Really? I didn't know that. At least it's not documented. The [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/apt-get.8.html), under SYNOPSIS, states only install, remove, purge, source and build-dep accept package lists.

Comment: But I just tested and you're right.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove liba you should run `apt remove liba`. Then you can run `apt autoremove` to remove any other dependencies of `liba` that is not used anymore.

`apt` keeps (1) a list of packages that you install and (2) a list of packages that automatically installed because it was dependencies on the packages that you installed. So when you call `apt autoremove` it checks these lists for packages that (1) you didn't install on your own and (2) also that are not dependencies to other packages anymore.