# why autoremove is not called whenever I remove a package?

Tags: apt

`man apt-get` says:

> autoremove is used to remove packages that were automatically installed to satisfy dependencies for other packages and are now no longer needed.

So why is it not automatically called every time I remove package?

#### EDIT

Essentially, my question is:  Why use `remove <pkg name>` and not `autoremove <pkg name>` to remove packages.

**[See here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto)**

PS: This won't break dependency as said [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/294024/will-apt-get-autoremove-break-other-dependencies)

Comment: This comment is just to clarify to people. I think what Sourabh is basically asking is "why does `apt-get remove` not remove the unneeded dependencies? Why do we have to do `apt-get autoremove` after it? Why doesn't `remove` just remove the dependencies by default; is there a purpose for keeping the now unneeded dependencies? Why not just use `autoremove <package>` instead of `remove <package>`?" Correct? I think the best answer to this question would be the one that answers "is there a purpose for keeping unneeded dependencies?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the **[AptGet/Howto - Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto)** page to clear your doubts.

It says:

```
apt-get autoremove
```

This command removes packages that were installed by other packages and are no longer needed.

```
apt-get autoremove <package_name>
```

This command removes an installed package and dependencies.

and

```
apt-get remove <package_name>
```

This command removes an installed package, leaving configuration files intact.

**EDIT**

It depends on how much you trust the dependancy tracker. While almost always correct, there are times when you would want a dependancy to remain, particularly when you are a developer or power user installing software that is not in the repository.

If you always install software through apt-get, without exception, and trust all the dependancies to be correct (which they usually are), then you can use **`apt-get autoremove`** and gain a small amount of drive space and a reduced exposure to potential security holes by having it remove packages that no longer have any packages that need them.

But if you install software manually, or develop software, or do not want to deal with a possible dependancy error, then not using autoremove to clear potentially unused packages is probably the safer choice. Regardless of whether you use `apt-get autoremove` every now and then or not, you will always remove software using **`apt-get remove Package`**

For example, if I install `AwesomePackage`, it may depend on `AwesomeLibrary`, and thus `AwesomeLibrary` will get automatically installed as a **dependancy**. When I remove `AwesomePackage` using autoremove, as long as no other package has `AwesomeLibrary` as a dependancy it will be uninstalled as well. But if `SuperPackage` also requires `AwesomeLibrary`, or if I had installed `AwesomeLibrary` explicitly myself rather than having it come in automatically as a dependancy (`apt-get install AwesomeLibrary`), then autoremove would not get rid of it.

The reason it is not the default is that having `AwesomeLibrary` on the system, unused, is a very minor issue. It will almost never cause problems, and most dependancies don't take up much space. There are exceptions, but the times when removing a dependancy will cause problems outnumber the times when it will solve or prevent a problem.

**Source: [SuperUser: When would you use apt-get remove over apt-get autoremove?](https://superuser.com/questions/398670/when-would-you-use-apt-get-remove-over-apt-get-autoremove)**

Comment: but my question is: `Why not remove all packages that were installed  by other packages and are no longer needed when the original package is removed`, in other words, why use `remove <pkg name>` and not `autoremove <pkg name>` for removing packages.

Answer (score 1):

> Why not remove all packages that were installed by other packages and are no longer needed when the original package is removed?

Because, `remove` only remove the package that you want to remove, not it's dependencies. Let see:

I installed `xorg` which depends (among other things) of `xserver-xorg`. `xserver-xorg` is marked as *Automatic*, and while I keep installed `xorg` it will not be uninstalled by `autoremove`. Now, I call `apt-get remove xorg`, which tells apt-get to do whatever it takes to remove `xorg`, and since it only needs to remove that package it doesn't take further action. Why? Because you only told him to remove **that** package and nothing else. You didn't tell him what to do with the dependencies, nor with other packages. `apt-get` is a good boy and follow your order with dot and comma, without trying to be smart doing things you didn't ask him to do, and I like it that way.

With `apt-get autoremove xorg` you tell apt-get to do whatever it takes to remove `xorg` and any *Automatic* dependency that was installed by `xorg`. Then `apt-get` follows your order and remove `xorg` and `xserver-xorg` and any other dependency of `xorg` that is marked as *Automatic* and don't have any other dependency to fulfill.

Lets take another scenario, I installed `xorg` and `xserver-xorg` and none is marked as *Automatic*. If I call `remove` on `xorg` only xorg will be deleted. If I call `autoremove` on `xorg` only xorg will be deleted. If I call `remove` on `xserver-xorg`, both xserver-xorg and xorg will get deleted, because you are telling apt-get to do whatever it takes to remove xserver-xorg but since xorg also depends of xserver-xorg, apt-get don't want to leave broken dependencies while following your orders, hence delete it.

But here is the fun, if you call `autoremove` on `xserver-xorg` it will uninstall any dependency marked as *Automatic* of xserver-xorg and xorg itself. Weird, huh? This is because apt-get takes this set of orders from you. In a nutshell, this are the actions, in the exact order, you tell apt-get whenever you call:

**`apt-get autoremove xserver-xorg`**

- Remove any reverse dependency of xserver-xorg. In this case *xorg*
- Remove xserver-xorg.
- Remove any package that xserver-xorg depends upon and is marked as automatic.
- Don't do anything else.

**`apt-get remove xserver-xorg`**

- Remove any reverse dependency of xserver-xorg. In this case *xorg*
- Remove xserver-xorg.
- Don't do anything else.

**`apt-get remove xorg`**

- Remove any reverse dependency of xorg. In this case *none*
- Remove xorg.
- Don't do anything else.

**`apt-get autoremove xorg`**

- Remove any reverse dependency of xorg. In this case *none*
- Remove xorg.
- Remove any package that xorg depends upon and is marked as automatic. If xserver-xorg is marked as automatic, it will get removed. If it's not it will be kept installed.
- Don't do anything else.

As you can see, every set of order has in the end *"Don't do anything else"* once he fulfilled every command. That is why you only remove only the target with remove.