# Is it safe to execute sudo apt-get autoremove after every update

Tags: command-line, apt, sudo

I always prefer keeping my disk optimized by using the above command. I wanted to know whether this is a safe practice. I am using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Yes, it is safe to run sudo apt-get autoremove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! It actually tells you to run it on most updates.

Comment: I have heard that it can break the dependencies. Is it true?

Comment: Reference....http://askubuntu.com/questions/294024/will-apt-get-autoremove-break-other-dependencies

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is safe. This command just removes the packages that were installed by other packages but are no longer needed.